# oracle listener supports no service

Tags: oracle, listener

I am having trouble with my Oracle instance.

I get the following error when I run lsnrctl stat in command prompt. I even confirmed Oracle services running.

The listener supports no services.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the platform is Windows and the Oracle version is 11g.
When an Oracle database instance starts, it tries to register itself to the default listener or to the listener registered in the init parameters as the local_listener. What you can do is

- make sure that your local_listener parameter points to your listener
- make sure that your listener runs on localhost port 1521 (using the listener.ora file)

This is when the database is using a dynamic listener. You could also make the listener a static one by entering the instance details in the listener.ora file. Docu about the listener.ora is found here [Oracle Net Listener Parameters (listener.ora)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/listener.htm#NETRF008)

Answer (score 0):

when the listener is created after creation of database,we need to explicitly register our instance.

try:

starting database by doing startup and check the listerner status by lsnrctl status and it your instance is running it means pmon has done registering your instance with the listener itself.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is very simple for this error, first, let's understand why this error occurs. It basically has two reasons which are:

1) Your database and service name is not properly set in Oracle environment it should be same everywhere check below parameter values

```
-ORACLE_SID in oracle environment.
-Check Database Instance name.
-SID_NAME in tnsnames.ora file.
-SERVICE_NAME in listener.ora file.
```

2) Host name/IP address is missing, not correct or spelling mistake, so please check the below.

```
-Check the IP ADDRESS in /etc/hosts file.
-It should be same in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora file
-And it should be able to ping from the local and remote server.
```

Now see I've also faced the same problem and resolved:

please visit this StackOverflow link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45065640/6332029

I hope it will help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was easy - for some reason, after restarting my laptop, services stopped working.
So, Run > services > start OracleService  helped to start the listener

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the latest Oracle 19c version with CentOS 8 installation.

So there is a bug with this Oracle DB instance.

**What happens:**  When you install the ORACLE DB, it automatically creates the listener with an instance. The problem exist in the Hierarchy File System of Linux and how the permission is distributed between the Sudo User group and the non-oracle User.

**What you have to do :**

Okay to solve this,  you have to open your bash profile

1. `***nano ~/.bash_profile***`
   this is equivalent to environment variables in Windows.
2. write text in editor: ***export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/{oracle-version}/dbhome_1***

   Save & Exit
3. Execute: ***export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/{oracle-version}/dbhome_1***
4. test the environment variable  :
   ***Echo $ORACLE_HOME***     -- should display result
5. execute ***chmod 777 /home***
6. execute ***chown -R oracle /home***
7. open terminal  ***su oracle && cd /u01/app/oracle/product/{oracle-version}/dbhome_1/bin***
8. with oracle account execute  ***./lsnrctl start***    -- it should run with no services still
9. execute: ***su {root account} && sudo ./dbstart***

   ```
    it should run run with 1 or 2 error.. its fine as long as it doesn't say "ORACLE_HOME is not set"
   ```
10. go back to execute:  ***su oracle && ./lsnrctl status***  with non root account

That's it.. it should now connect with your service and handler, should give the instance of your db name to connect with.  You can use the **sys as sysdba and password** during installation to log into the database.

Answer (score 0):

After starting the listener service I had to wait 60 seconds before the services would show up as running. So if you enter "lsnrctl stop" followed by "lsnrctl start" you might have to wait a minute before "lsnrctl status" will show your listener services.

Answer (score -1):

I did check all the things but could not find the cause. So I re-installed the Oracle and using that now.