# Why Oracle listener and database service not running?

Tags: oracle11g, redhat

I am just starting to get my feet wet in Red Hat Linux 7.2 and Oracle 12c.  So I spent last weekend devoted to in an attempt to see if I could stand up Oracle 12c on RHEL 7.2.  In the end and yes, I was able to stand up Oracle on a RHEL 7.2 VM but not without problems - a lot of them.  But I managed to resolve 
them one at a time.  I blew away my VM and started everything from scratch again.

Now I think I have a pretty good setup up & running.  The only thing I don't understand is when I reboot my Linux box, both the Oracle listner and the database service do not start automatically as they do on a Windows Server 2012 R2 system.  If these services are not running, naturally I can't connect
to the Oracle DB.  To fix it, I have to run these two commands:

1. Logon as the oracle user
2. Run lsnrctl start

   I will see a message something like: The listener supports no services
    This is fine.
3. Connect to the database and run

   sql>startup

After that, everything is running as normal.  I can connect to the Oracle db from any Oracle client.  My questions are: Is this the normal behavior on a Linux box?  Did I miss something during the Oracle install?  If these services are supposed to start automatically, what do I need to do to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I continued to Google about my issue but haven't found a solution.  I found out the Oracle script to start the database.  I need to run $ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart.  How do I run this program at bootup?

Answer (score 1):

This error solution is very simple, first, let's understand why this error occurs. It basically has two reasons which are:

1) Your database and service name is not properly set in Oracle environment it should be same everywhere check below parameter values

```
-ORACLE_SID in oracle environment.
-SID_NAME in tnsnames.ora file.
-SERVICE_NAME in listener.ora file.
```

2) Host name/IP address is missing, not correct or spelling mistake, so please check the below.

```
-Check the IP ADDRESS in /etc/hosts file.
-It should be same in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora file
-And it should be able to ping from the local and remote server.
```

Now see I've also faced the same problem and resolved:

```
[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jul 12 22:52:29 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  970895360 bytes
Fixed Size          1340636 bytes
Variable Size         713034532 bytes
Database Buffers      251658240 bytes
Redo Buffers            4861952 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> 
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 12-JUL-2017 22:54:51

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521)))

TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
LSNRCTL> LSNRCTL> start
Starting /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1//bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/OLE1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                12-JUL-2017 22:55:43
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 23 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/OLE1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL> [oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ echo $ORACLE_SID
orcl
[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ cat tnsnames.ora 
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ole1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ cat listener.ora 
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ole1 )(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /home/oracle/app/oracle

[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost
192.168.244.128 ole1
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ tnsping orcl

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 12-JUL-2017 22:57:14

Copyright (c) 1997, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ole1)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 12-JUL-2017 23:01:48

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> 
LSNRCTL>
LSNRCTL> reload
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL> 
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                12-JUL-2017 22:55:43
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 6 min. 37 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/OLE1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL> stop
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL> start
Starting /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1//bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/OLE1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                12-JUL-2017 23:03:10
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 21 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/OLE1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL> 

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jul 12 23:04:37 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select name from v$database;

NAME
---------
ORCL

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$

[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost
192.168.244.128 ole1
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ ping ole1
PING ole1 (192.168.244.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- ole1 ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 13710ms

[oracle@OLE1 admin]$
```

**Note:** Now here I found the problem in IP address configuration its not pinging, So i did some changes in eth1 driver of my OS in VMware machine.

```
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ ping ole1
PING ole1 (192.168.244.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ole1 (192.168.244.128): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.694 ms
64 bytes from ole1 (192.168.244.128): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.187 ms
64 bytes from ole1 (192.168.244.128): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=4.96 ms
64 bytes from ole1 (192.168.244.128): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.121 ms
64 bytes from ole1 (192.168.244.128): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
64 bytes from ole1 (192.168.244.128): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.166 ms
64 bytes from ole1 (192.168.244.128): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.126 ms
^C
--- ole1 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6996ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.082/0.905/4.963/1.668 ms
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ lsnrctl 

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 12-JUL-2017 23:09:37

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> stop
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL> 
LSNRCTL> 
LSNRCTL> start   
Starting /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1//bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/OLE1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                12-JUL-2017 23:09:45
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/OLE1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL> 
LSNRCTL> 
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                12-JUL-2017 23:09:45
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 2 min. 17 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/OLE1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jul 13 00:15:48 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$
```

Now it's running fine for me, I hope it will help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check listener log for details.

Find listener log location with:

```
$ lsnrctl stat

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version  . . . 
. . . 
Listener Log File        /home/app/oracle/product/10.2/network/log/listener.log
```

Comment: I found the solution here https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/automating-database-startup-and-shutdown-on-linux